# Is there a way to transfer multiple 10s of GB?

Tags: data-transfer, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to transfer multiple 10s of GB, I don't know yet the right value but let's say between 20 and 40 GB.

This is a wordpress instance, and yes I have no idea how can someone generate so many content.

I've looked at stuff like WeTransfer and SendSpace but they have a low limit (20 GB and 10 GB) for my situation.

What would be a solution for this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

OK, so maybe this was not the best way to ask the question.

I added the wordpress tag because I'm sure other wordpress users must have been faced with similar problems.

**What I want to achieve:** provide a way for a company to transfer over to me a wordpress install that currently occupies +20GB of space. **update**: direct access (ssh/ftp) to the current servers is not a option at this time

**What I've found so far:**

- big data transfer services like WeTransfer seem to be caped at 20GB
- opening up my own servers does not seem to be the best way to go about this (security issues and bandwidth costs)

So essentially I'm trying to find how people normally transfer these types of installations.

Any suggestion is apreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "transfer"? To where? Is that the file size or the total size?

Comment: Hi @MátéJuhász, this is a wordpress instance that is under the control of another company that I need to have transferred to me. And the value is total yes, but it would be hard to transfer one file at a time.

Comment: then your question sounds off-topic here (please also read description of wordpress tag)

Comment: Amend question (don't add comments to amend, just edit the question).

Comment: Can you clarify the question. As it stands the answer is one byte at a time (as for all transfers). But I am sure that this is not the answer that you are looking for. Therefore you need to make the question clearer. Tell us what you are trying to achieve; What you have tried; What went wrong (or that you pensive will go wrong (be clear which it is)).

Comment: Copy and paste always works for me.  I specifically mean, download the files, then upload them to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

A business WordPress will inevitably be installed on an in-house server or hosted by a hosting company.

As WordPress is just a load of files and is usually uploaded (or installed by some script) then the original company will have some FTP or webspace access so they can manage the WordPress files on a granular basis.

If you need to download then would it not be easier to contact the company you're copying the WordPress install from and ask them for FTP details - you can then use your own FTP software (FileZilla etc.) to download the files to your own computer and then with them what you need.

Comment: thanks, yes that would be the most normal solution, but in this case the company is being unhelpful and they don't want to give me direct access to their server. This is why I need to find a way around it.

Comment: You should update your question with this information as it may help your cause and to improve your question.